# Cintiq pen pressure not working in texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

I can't get the pen pressure option to work, best way to describe it is permanently stuck at full pressure. The worst part is I was able to use it normally maybe a month ago.

I'm pretty sure it's blender and not my drivers or the cintiq itself as the pen pressure works fine in other programs. I've already tried restarting/stop and starting the tablet driver, restarting my computer, opening blender with my cintiq pen, turning off strength and only having pen pressure selected, switching to blender render instead of cycles, and I've unplugged and re-plugged in my tablet.

The best I can figure is based on the only other case I could find that was similar, where blender was registering the tablet as a mouse behind the scenes. Problem is, that case was for yiynova tablet on a linux computer, and I have windows.

Any ideas on what process might be off would be off and how to fix it would be appreciated
[image]

Comment: If you were able to use it normally before that means that something changed in your settings or OS. If you are using auto-updating in windows it is likely that the drivers or other config files have been broken. Re-install and reconfigure the drivers for the tablet.

Comment: I have this issue with my Huion sometimes, you need to clean reinstall your tablet drivers most likely.

Answer (score 2):

I reinstalled the tablet program from the cintiq disk, restarted, and that was enough. I presume it *was* from windows updating as that's the only thing that changed.

Comment: Agree with the solutions presented (Huion GT-191 v1 pen display): Reinstall Huion driver (but as per usual Huion, remember to uninstall ALL TABLET DRIVERS first, then install Huion drivers.)
My problem was worse. Painting with the pen applies a transparency/alpha, not paint. But using the mouse actually paints colors.
Weird.
(I've tried changing Blender stettings, tweaking painting options: nothing worked)